# What would aliens with 'automated muscles' be like?

Tags: evolution, xenobiology, aliens

The automated muscles would be an alternative to animal muscles, which consist of a tissue that contracts like muscles, but does this on a cyclic 'timetable' which is synchronised across the entire muscle. The 'timetables' would vary by species and location of the muscle. Some muscles might gain an extra 'timetable', which would allow the muscle to do multiple things. The activity of the muscles would be controlled by nerves. This nervous control would serve both to select which 'timetable' to follow, and would also be able to alter the motions. So, if alien life evolved with this tissue in place of animal muscle, what are some unique features that would be expected?

Comment: Have you considered the function of the heart, diaphragm and oesophageal muscles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not significantly different from normal Earthling animals.

What you are describing is essentially identical to the effect of autonomic / reflexive nervous system control. So, these creatures have autonomic functions built directly into the muscles tissue rather than encoded in the nervous system. That will alter the organization of the nervous system--its lower-level functions will be simpler, since some of the things it would otherwise have to handle are now handled elsewhere instead--but not the mechanical possibilities available to the body as a whole.

Comment: To add to this: our brains basically already do this. If you want to grab a cup on the table, a pattern us activated in the motor cortex. The pattern is always the same. Interestingly this is regardless of position of your arm and hand. The movement is monitored and corrected, but one pattern is active in the brain (unless something exotic happens). You just move the identical patterns to the muscles.

Comment: @Trioxidane: Even more so with repetitive actions like running, which you don't really think about unless you need to modify the pattern, for instance to avoid that rock or pile of bear scat in the trail.